# Could not find xml-config package in Fedora

Tags: linux, package, apt

While executing ./configure of gnorpm, this error message is appear.

```
configure: error: Could not find xml-config.
```

I find this document in google.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xml-config-not-found-777868/

I install gstreamer, libxml2 as that document says.

It also says execute

```
apt-get install libghttp1 libhttp-ghttp-perl libghttp-dev
```

But in my fedora, same error message appears.

```
E: Couldn't find package libghttp1.
```

and ./configure still occurs error.

What package should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that `gnorpm` is ancient - indeed it looks like it is practically prehistoric. These days `libxml2` seems to use `xml2-config` rather than `xml-config` so I suspect that `gnorpm` wants a really old version of `libxml2` that modern systems probably don't have.

Comment: I understand what is problem. Thank you very much for your answer.